# How can I skew an object?

Tags: mesh

I have a complex mesh that I would like to change the proportions to. Using this mesh as a simplified example, how to I make this:

[image: unskewed square]

Into this?

[image: skewed square]

Again, the mesh I'm working with is complex, so simplifying it into a 6-sided square, shrinking one face, then subdividing it would not be a viable option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this non-destructively using a *Simple Deform Modifier*.

1. Select the desired mesh
2. In the modifiers tab add a *Simple Deform Modifier*
3. Set the type to *Taper*
4. Adjust *Factor* to increase/decrease the amount of deformation.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways you can do it.

1. Resizing with proportional editing.
2. Using a modifier like lattice, or mesh deform using another object to control the deformation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Explain more precisely steps for each solution, it would be better ;)